# Mock promise value jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I try to mock a promise response for testing in reactjs, I expect when mock the response and then the return will change.

```
other.js

const handler: () => Promise<boolean> = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(true);
  });

const parr = () => ({ handler });

export { parr };
```

```
item.test.tsx

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import { parr } from './other';

const Co = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const { handler } = parr();
  useEffect(() => {
    handler().then(val => setState(val));
  }, [handler]);

  if (state) return <div data-test-id="one" />;
  return <div data-test-id="two" />;
};

jest.mock('./other', () => ({
  parr: jest.fn(),
}));

test('x', () => {
  (parr as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
    handler: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
  });
  render(<Co />);
  expect(screen.getByTestId('one')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-test-id="one"]

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          data-test-id="two"
        />
      </div>
    </body>
```

after mock the response, still got same result, is there any solution for this ? Is there any other way to mock this component?

Comment: It's a _promise_, it's asynchronous. What happens if you e.g. `await screen.findByTestId("one")`?